# Copy new created file to annother folder

Tags: command-line, scripts, files, rsync, copy

I have folder A where a new pdf file is created automatically at irregular time occurrence from an external process. This is my archive folder. It should remain untouched. I need to make a copy of only this last created file to annother folder called B so that I can process it further. So whenever a new file is created I need a copy of just this new file to folder B. Intuitively I thought about using incrontab to monitor the event. Rsync does not looks able to satisfy my needs.

Comment: Look up how to use a systemd "path" unit file to monitor a directory and to trigger a .service when that directory changes.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? What types of filesystems are source and destination? Read `man -k inotify`. Could you check every N minutes? `man -a crontab`. Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask